# Find function given its complex Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

The complex Fourier series coefficients of a function with periodicity 4 are as follows:
$$C_k=\frac{\sin{k\frac{\pi}{8}}}{2k\pi}$$
Find this function.

I really have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier series coefficients of Rectangular signal with amplitude $A$ is :

$\frac{A}{T}\frac{sin(\frac{k\pi}{T})}{\frac{k\pi}{T}}$. If you compare this with your given coefficient you can find the parameter of the rectangle.